# Data import, analysis and exporting a JSON file by using python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, parsing, python-requests

I downloaded a JSON file by using the services offered by [API-Football](https://www.api-football.com/) using python and its package *requests*.
I wrote down the following code to download the JSON file from the web:

```
import requests as requests

# URL
url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues"

headers = {
    # Host: API Football (v3.football.api-sports.io)
    'x-rapidapi-host': "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    # RapidAPI Key available on https://rapidapi.com/developer/security/API-Football
    'x-rapidapi-key': "YOUR-API-KEY"
    }

response = requests.request("GET",
                            url,
                            headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Such piece of code works fine, but I'm not able to view that as a table or a data-frame and to analyze that.

I'm a rookie in python and I would like to view such data in a data-frame format.

Specifically, I need to understand how to navigate the JSON file and extract data; for instance, by subsetting data for a given time window (season_start between 2 dates) and select a little of variable (e.g. country and league).

Does it exist a way to transform such 'str' object in a data-frame with the relative variable names? Specifically, I need to convert *response.text* object in a data-frame or a .csv file.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to make a dataframe from JSON which is what requests returns. In the future, please include the output that you would like to transform into a dataframe

Comment: Yes, making a data-frame from a JSON file is what I want to do, but I'm not able to do that till now. As regards the output is not important, because I just need to understand as to do that.. For instance, it would be enough to transform the first 2 variables or any variables (e.g.: 'country', 'season_start','season_end') for a limited time window (e.g.: season_start from 2020-01-01 to 2022-01-01) @georgwalker45

Answer (score 0):

This api provides data in json format, there are list of objects inside `api` -> `leagues` key, so you need to convert this list to pandas DataFrame

Here is code to do so:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your code from question goes here

data = response.json()['api']['leagues']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, but running pd.DataFrame(data['api']['leagues']) I got error; specifically one returns "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". 'str' is the object type.

Comment: Hi, fixed code in answer, please check it now, also consider marking it as "accepted" if it helps you

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried again with what you posted, but no way.. one returns the same error as before.